# Не понимаю как работает Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Хочу обернуть теги вида: #янаморе, #какдела. В кликаблельные ссылки.

```
public String replaceDiesTags(String text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, "(^|\\s)([#＃][\\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*[\\p{L}_]+[\\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*)", "<a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>");
}
```

Регекс вроде правильный, но не возвращает value.

Объясните пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Comment: конструкция `(^|\\s)` обычно записывается как `\b` (читается как граница слова). И raw строки там есть. Поэтому саму регулярку я бы сократил до `@"\b([#＃][^ ]+)"` И уже на ней тестил.

Comment: По моему двойные слэши лишние. Должны быть одинарные.

Comment: @coder675, не должны без `@`.

Comment: Предлагаю вам начать с такого паттерна: `(#[\p{L}\p{N}]+)`. Ну и строчка, на которую вы пытаетесь заменить не верна, вам нужна она такого плана: `<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>`

Comment: Код вырван из контекста. См. [демо регулярки](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5b%23%ef%bc%83%5d%5b%5cw%5cu05be%5cu05f3%5cu05f4%5d*%5b%5cp%7bL%7d_%5d%2b%5b%5cw%5cu05be%5cu05f3%5cu05f4%5d*&i=%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83+%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c+%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8+%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%3a+%23%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%2c+%23%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0.&r=%3ca+href%3d%22%7b0%7d%22%3e%7b0%7d%3c%2fa%3e), это то, что надо?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, да то что надо. Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
public String replaceDiesTags(String text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!\S)[#＃][\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*[\p{L}_]+[\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*", "<a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>");
}
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5b%23%ef%bc%83%5d%5b%5cw%5cu05be%5cu05f3%5cu05f4%5d%2A%5b%5cp%7bL%7d_%5d%2b%5b%5cw%5cu05be%5cu05f3%5cu05f4%5d%2A&i=%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83+%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c+%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8+%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%3a+%23%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%2c+%23%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0.&r=%3ca+href%3d%22%7b0%7d%22%3e%7b0%7d%3c%2fa%3e)

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\S)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, требует пробельный символ или начало строки сразу слева от текущей позиции
- `[#＃]` - знак `＃` или `#`
- `[\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*` - 0 или более букв, цифр, `_`, а также знаки Юникода  `\u05be`, `\u05f3` и `\u05f4`
- `[\p{L}_]+` - 1 или более букв или `_`
- `[\w\u05be\u05f3\u05f4]*` - 0 или более букв, цифр, `_`, а также знаки Юникода  `\u05be`, `\u05f3` и `\u05f4`